# Extracting multiple values from a column to a new column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **df** having a column name *Category* and the values inside are

**Category**

Furniture

Technology

Office Supply


These three values are repeated having total of 1000 values in the column. I want to create a new column name **Category_filter** having values *Furniture* and *Technology* from the **Category** column.

```
df['Category_Filter'] = df[df['Category'].isin(['Furniture', 'Technology'])]
```

I have tried the above code to create new column but not working.

```
Category_Filter
Furniture
Technology
```

This is the desired output

Comment: What is your desired output? it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you want a dataframe where the values in 'Category' are either 'Furniture' or 'Technology'. Here's something you can do.

```
df[df['Category'].isin(['Furniture ', 'Technology '])]
```

If this isn't what you meant, perhaps you could clarify.

EDIT: Responding to your comment below:

```
 df['Category_filter'] = df['Category'].where(df['Category'].isin(['Furniture ', 'Technology ']))
```

Comment: I want to create a new column in that existing dataframe having only values Furniture and Technoloy from that Category column

Comment: please see my edit. Also, since you used my code in your edited question, please accept/upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If i underst0od you correctly, you are looking for the total counts of values repeated for each element in the column.

Example dataFrame:

```
>>> df
        Category
0      Furniture
1     Technology
2  Office Supply
3      Furniture
4     Technology
5  Office Supply
6      Furniture
7     Technology
8  Office Supply
```

As per your updated code  it shoule woek, only the values which you are  not matching those will be reported as `NaN`..

```
>>> df['Category_Filter'] = df[df['Category'].isin(['Furniture', 'Technology'])]
>>> df
        Category Category_Filter
0      Furniture       Furniture
1     Technology      Technology
2  Office Supply             NaN
3      Furniture       Furniture
4     Technology      Technology
5  Office Supply             NaN
6      Furniture       Furniture
7     Technology      Technology
8  Office Supply             NaN
```

Or if you  want all rows to be dropped with having `NaN` values the simply try :

```
>>> df.dropna()
# df.dropna(inplace=True)   # make in permanent to the DataFrame
     Category Category_Filter
0   Furniture       Furniture
1  Technology      Technology
3   Furniture       Furniture
4  Technology      Technology
6   Furniture       Furniture
7  Technology      Technology
```